# Getting Socket.io to work with newly SSL Encrypted website

Tags: node.js, ssl, encryption, https, socket.io

Sorry if I'm missing some information, this is my first post on stackoverflow.

I've had my website that had regular http requests but today I've added SSL Encryption to my website as I've heard it'll attract better traffic to my website, however after I've added SSL to my website I'm getting errors from socket.io: "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".

EDIT: Another important note is that when I type in the url with http and not htttps the socket connects to the port.

This is what the server side uses to connect to the port:
var io = require('socket.io')(4002);

This is what the client uses to connect to the port:

var HOST = ":4002";
SOCKET = io(HOST);

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please show us the code you use to make the socket.io connection?  And, the server-side code you use to listen for the connection?  Questions about code should include the relevant code pasted into the question itself.

Comment: This is what the server side uses to connect to the port:
var io = require('socket.io')(4002);

This is what the client uses to connect to the port:

var HOST = ":4002";
SOCKET = io(HOST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly from previous troubleshooting, the client function `io()` must either take no parameters (in which case it connects back to the same origin as the containing web page was loaded or it must be passed an actual URL.

So, when you do:

```
var HOST = ":4002";   
io(HOST);
```

you are doing:

```
io(":4002");
```

which is not a form that it understands.  Here are some forms that would work:

```
io();                        // connect to same host and port as the containing webpage
io("https://somehost:4002");  // connect to specific host and port
```

The specific documentation for `io()` is [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#iourl-options).

```
io(url[, options])

url (String) 
options (Object) 
Returns Socket
```

Where it says `url`, it is expecting an actual URL, formatted as a URL.

---

To create an https server to use with socket.io, you create the server first and then pass the server to socket.io like this:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('agent2-cert.pem')
};

// create server and start it
const server = https.createServer(options).listen(4002);

// attach socket.io to your server
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// attach event handlers to socket.io
io.on('connection', ....);
```

See [socket.io https documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) for more details on creating the https server.

---

You can listen for and log errors that might be happening on the server side like this:

```
server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
    console.log("clientError", err);
}).on('error', err => {
    console.log("serverError", err);
});
```

Comment: It works the same way if I just type :4002 as I'm ready data from my localhost, just to make sure I did as you asked:

SOCKET = io("https://csgopole.com:4002");

When I try to access the website with https it still gives me the error:

ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I'm assuming this has to due with something in the server side, the code I used to connect to the port with the server side is:

var io = require('socket.io')(4002);

Comment: Use a full URL  with the proper protocol.

Comment: I used a full URL for some reason it removed it in the comments. I used https

Comment: It just sounds like you don't have proper configuration for https since it works with http.

Comment: For the server side do you think var io = require('socket.io')("https:csgopole.com:4002"); Will work?

Comment: @JacobF - No, that will not work.  To use https, you have to create your own https server (with appropriate certificate) and then pass that to socket.io.  socket.io cannot create an https server for you like it can for http.

Comment: I have an https certificate, the thing is that as you can see I don't really know how to create an https server, I've only used socket.io which as you said creates an http connection, not https.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how I can create an https server?

Comment: @JacobF - I added to the end of my answer how to use socket.io with https.

Comment: Ok nice, but where do I get agent2-key.pem and agent2-cert.pem

Comment: This is what I typed for the server side code connection:

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('apache-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('apache-cert.pem')
};
var server = https.createServer(options).listen(4002);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

This is what I typed for the client side port connection:

SOCKET = io("https://csgopole.com:4002");

For the key and cert files I just copied my certificate file and private key and renamed it to this with a .pem extension, however I'm still getting this error:

ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: Hello..? Nothing?

Comment: @JacobF - As I've said several times now, the client side needs to be `var SOCKET = io("https://csgopole.com:4002")`.  You can check in the chrome debugger network tab to see what is happening with the initial https connection to the socket.io server and see if you can learn more from that.  If your https server is being created properly, this should work.  If it is not being created properly, then see the additional error logging I've added to the end of my answer which you can add to capture more info.  Also, I may not be notified of your comment unless you direct it to me with "@jfriend00".

Answer (score 0):

Try the connection with secure set to true.

```
 var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {secure: true});<br>
```

You can also do this: let your homepage load on normal http, then when the browser upgrades the protocol to websockets, then upgrade to https.

Comment: This is how I chose which port I wanted to use:
var io = require('socket.io')(4002);

Comment: But you must be initializing the connection somewhere in the code. That time, put socket as secure.